# Why Python counts 0 of starting non single digit as a string?

Tags: python

Actually I am beginner in Python. I just want to know why python gives error on print of integer which is starting with 0 (non single digit)

for e.g. if I type `09` in integer then on printing it gives error

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: Because Python thinks you are creating an octal number; in Python 3 that's always an error, in Python 2 octal numbers like 07 do work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 at the beginning of a numeric literal is used to tell python which base to use, for example: 0x12.

Using `09` you are expressing 9 in octal base but 9 is not a valid digit in that base and thus the error.

Comment: No, in Python 2, `07` is valid, but interpreted as octal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was expanding the answer. It is the same case, a numetic literal beginning with `0` means a numeric literal in a given base such as octal `0d` and hexadecimal `0xd` where d is the value expressed in that base.